# twitter prevent t.co url when tweet contains dots?

Tags: twitter

Seems like Twitter transforms some non URL string values to URL if the string contains dots, for example :

```
this.is.my.tweet
```

And twitter transforms that to

```
http://t.co/TSFXvQrr
```

Is there anyway to prevent that ?? This is a major bug !

Comment: Is this a coding issue or a use of Twitter issue?

Comment: Well both i guess. I'm using this with the Stream API but it happens will a normal tweet as well. Maybe there is some method i didn't find in STREAM to prevent that ?

Comment: Have you tried asking [Twitter Support](http://support.twitter.com/) for... I don't know... support with Twitter?

Comment: Actually, that looks like a valid URL to me, although it misses the http:// part. Blame ICANN.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt i have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: Tom is saying that `this.is.my.tweet` may indeed be a valid URL since the ICANN has plans to allow registration of top level domains for companies, at which point .tweet may become a valid TLD, just like .com is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your not the one inputting the tweet but instead are reading from the stream than there isn't much you can do with the way Twitter handles the rendering when it's already in the system. What you can do is see the resolved text behind it with `tweet_entities` . Tweet entities will give you the real URL (or fake URL) behind the t.co.

According to the text, Tweet Entities is enabled by default with the Streaming API and can be called with the REST api with an added `&include_entities=1`

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities

Comment: Well i'm phucked then :) thanks tho.